# CSS - Align Text, Input and Image in DIV

Tags: html, css, image, input, alignment

I'm trying to align some text, and input field and an image which is approx 25x25 px

What I get is the text and Image at the top of the div and the input slightly lower down.

How do I align them so they are all vertically level with each other.

This is what I have so far:

```
div.block {overflow:hidden; border:1px solid #000 }
div.block label {width:150px; display:block; float:left; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; }
div.block.input {margin-left:4px; float:left; vertical-align:middle; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a3cmfpzL/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is for **Horizontal**:

```css
.block{
  display:flex;
}
label{
  border:1px solid red;
}

img{
  height:25px;
  width:25px;
}
```

```html
<div class='block'>
<label>Test Label</label>
<input type='text' value='1234567890'/>
<img src='http://placekitten.com/301/301'/>
</div>
```

If you're looking for **Vertical** direction then:

```css
*{
  border:0;
  padding:0;
}
.block{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
label{
  border:1px solid red;
 width:100px;
}

img{
  height:25px;
  width:25px;
}
```

```html
<div class='block'>
<label>Test Label</label>
<input type='text' value='1234567890'/>
<img src='http://placekitten.com/301/301'/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position:absolute` and `display:flex` inside your div.block.
That should do the trick if I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise you to use flexbox.

Can be a bit confusing at the beginning, but once you get the hang of it, you'll love it.
Here you can find a perfect guide for using it.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Something like this (just written out of my mind, so untested)
Try removing your classes first.

Your CSS

```
.flex {
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between; // only use this if you don't justify-self the elements
}

.border {
    border:1px solid #000;
}

img {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    justify-self: top; // if you don't use flex-direction on .flex
}

input {
    justify-self: top; // if you don't use flex-direction on .flex
}
```

Your HTML

```
<div style="flex border">
    <img src='image.png'/>
    <label>Test Label</label>
    <input type='text' value='1234567890'/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Few Issues**

1. This `div.block.input` isn't selecting anything so all those styles aren't being used
2. You made the label a block level element so it won't respond to the `vertical-align` property.

The `<input>` and the `<img>` are inline elements so they will share the same line box in which they live, Their vertical alignment will be set by the `vertical-align` property.

The default value for `vertical-align` property is baseline:

> Align the baseline of the box with the baseline of the parent box. If the box does not have a baseline, align the bottom margin edge with the parent's baseline.

In this case we have an `<img>` which doesn't have a baseline, So it will be aligned based on it's bottom margin, in our case the img have no margin so it's basically the bottom edge.

The `<input>` However have a baseline, So it's baseline will be aligned with the bottom edge of the img next to it.

### DEMO

```css
div.block {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000
}

div.block label {
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div.block.input {
  margin-left: 4px;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div {
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(red, red) 0 24.5px/ 100% 1px no-repeat
}
```

```html
<p>red line is the baseline</p>
<div class='block'>
  <label>Test Label</label>
  <input type='text' value='1234567890' />
  <img src='https://i.picsum.photos/id/527/25/25.jpg' />
</div>
```

---

### Solutions

I cleaned the code a bit and remove unnecessary styles.

1. Floats aren't necessary
2. If you to apply a width to the label use `display:inline-block;` instead

**1) vertical-align: middle;**

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div.block {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000
}

label {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: brown;
}

input {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
  background: red;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class='block'>
  <label>Test Label</label>
  <input type='text' value='1234567890' />
  <img src='https://i.picsum.photos/id/527/25/25.jpg' />
</div>
```

Items will be aligned relative to middle of the tallest item which is the img.

**2) If you want elements to share the same height**

Knowing the `<img>` is the tallest and it's height, we can simple apply that same height to the other elements, We still need to apply `vertical-align:top` to align the elements based on their top edge instead of the baseline

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    
    /* because we defined a height on the element, 
       we need to ensure that any extra space should be   
       calculated within that height */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.block {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-size:0;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px;
    font-size:16px;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height:25px;
    background:brown;
}

input {
    height: 25px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border:0;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class='block'>
  <label>Test Label</label>
  <input type='text' value='1234567890' />
  <img src='https://i.picsum.photos/id/527/25/25.jpg' />
</div>
```

**3) Flexbox**

Which is the simplest and i won't be covering because it have been covered in other answers.